# How did a young Tom Riddle find his way to the Leaky Cauldron on his own?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In ***Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince***, Dumbledore leads Harry in his memories to Tom Riddle's orphanage. After having persuaded Tom, Dumbledore gives him some money, and Tom tells Dumbledore that he will find his way to Leaky Cauldron on his own. And he does.

Is there any clue that how a 10 year old boy who didn't have any knowledge about the magical world, could find the Leaky Cauldron on his own?

Answer (score 44):

Because Dumbledore gave him directions. This is the exact passage you’re referring to:

> Harry thought that Dumbledore would insist upon accompanying Riddle, but once again he was surprised. Dumbledore handed Riddle the envelope containing his list of equipment, and **after telling Riddle exactly how to get to the Leaky Cauldron from the orphanage**, he said, “You will be able to see it, although Muggles around you — non-magical people, that is — will not. Ask for Tom the barman — easy enough to remember, as he shares your name —”
>
> *Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 13 (*The Secret Riddle*)

Presumably Dumbledore’s directions were sufficiently detailed for Riddle to find his way.